# R: expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'

Tags: r, matlab, curve-fitting

```
require(OptionPricing)
c=BS_EC(K=54, r = 0.07, sigma = 0.3, T = 5/12, S0 = 50)
c[1]
y <- function(y) (BS_EC(K=54, r = 0.07, sigma = y, T = 5/12, S0 = 50)-2.846575)
```

This is done in matlab using fzero, I have implemented this in Python using lambda. Want to do same in R.

so far tried following:

```
> uniroot(y,c(-1,1))
Error in uniroot(y, c(-1, 1)) : 
  f() values at end points not of opposite sign
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (is.na(f.lower)) stop("f.lower = f(lower) is NA") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (is.na(f.upper)) stop("f.upper = f(upper) is NA") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

and

```
> f <- Vectorize(function(y) (BS_EC(K=54, r = 0.07, sigma = y, T = 5/12, S0 = 50)-2.846575))
> curve(f)
Error in curve(f) : 'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'
```

Also plot(); but no luck!

Please share an idea.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is BS_EC gives back a vector (price,delta,gamma) as result.
In order to apply a range of input you have to consider just one result at time.
For example for price add [1]

```
 f <- Vectorize(function(y) (BS_EC(K=54, r = 0.07, sigma = y, T = 5/12, S0 = 50)[1]-2.846575))
 curve(f)
```

The same is true for the optimization, you have to decide what parameter you want to consider
Again give back just the price with [1] and you are done

```
 y <- function(y) (BS_EC(K=54, r = 0.07, sigma = y, T = 5/12, S0 = 50)[1]-2.846575)
uniroot(y,c(-1,1))
```

Comment: Thank you Federico, it works perfect. Feeling like its a silly question to ask in first place now :)

Comment: Hi, There is no such thing like stupid question:). Learning new programming languages sometimes I get stuck in things that  I could have solved in seconds. One example? I lost one days trying to figuring out a isnumeric function in SAS

Comment: Your day long search shows you're a determined person. I think I sort gave up when I posted my question here. But it paid off quickly. Thanks to you once again.